# python 3.x and urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi i have a problem with my code im using python 3.6 and i open a file .txt and read the text for send to my urllib.request.urlopen() but i have a error i known that is for my txt file has spaces and \n but in python 2.7 work perfectly
here is my code :

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

def readtext():
        quotes = open("C:/Users/sdand/Documents/Python/udacity/curse.txt")
        contents_of_files = quotes.read()
        print(contents_of_files)
        quotes.close()
        check_profanity(contents_of_files)

def check_profanity(text):
        req = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text)
        output = req.read()
        req.close()


readtext()
```

and this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sdand/Documents/Python/udacity/profanity.py", line 17, in <module>
    readtext()
  File "C:/Users/sdand/Documents/Python/udacity/profanity.py", line 9, in readtext
    check_profanity(contents_of_files)
  File "C:/Users/sdand/Documents/Python/udacity/profanity.py", line 12, in check_profanity
    req = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

i appreciate you help thank you

Comment: that's just for see my text inside of contents_of_files:
-- Houston shit, we have a problem. (Apollo 13)

-- Mama always said, life is like a box of chocolates. You never know what you are going to get. (Forrest Gump)

-- You cant handle the truth. (A Few Good Men)

-- I believe everything and I believe nothing. (A Shot in the Dark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try escaping the query string:

```
def check_profanity(text):
  req = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?" + urllib.parse.urlencode([('q', text)]))
  output = req.read()
  req.close()
```

`urllib.request.urlopen`, sends a `GET` request to the url supplied. Apparently, it does not check if the string is url encoded and does not try to do it itself.

URLs cannot have many special characters in them (like spaces), and those need to be encoded to be a valid url (like replaceing `space` with `+`).

So basically, the content you read from the file is not encoded to be a proper http url. That is done by `urllib.parse.urlencode`.

`urllib.parse.urlencode` takes a list of tuple with a key, value pair.

Basically,

```
urllib.parse.urlencode([('q', 'value'), ('another', 'value with spaces & other *special* chars')])
# equals:
# q=value&another=value+with+spaces+%26+other+%2Aspecial%2A+chars
```

Which is ready to be consumed in a url.

Comment: That works thank you!, can you explain me what does  this portion urllib.parse.urlencode([('q', text)]) ?